# remove repeated items in a list variable in linux

Tags: linux, list, grep, uniq

Im having trouble with this.

Given a list such as  LIST="a b c . b c . d"   I would like to end up with OUTPUT="a b c . d"

Basically im looking to remove repeated items like the uniq command would but without reordering the list. so using sort i not an option.

```
OUTPUT=
for term in $LIST
do
if [[ -n $( echo "$OUTPUT" | grep -w $term ) ]]; then
echo "$term in output already"
else
OUTPUT="$OUTPUT $term "
echo "$term added to output"
fi
done
echo -e $OUTPUT
```

The problem with this option the .(dot) is recognized as a wildcard so it matches with anything already in the output. Im wondering if there is a smarter way to  do this or if there is a simple way to handle the dot(.)

Comment: So the duplicate answer did not work to you?

Comment: @fedorqui - It's similar but it is not a duplicate because the OP here needs to retain the original order, which will be lost if a sort were applied.  All the solutions to the other question include a sort - which is not surprising as that was asked for there.

Comment: Most of the answers in the dup use sort -u. This does remove the repeated items but reordering the items in the list is undesired.

Comment: Ok! Just reopened. Hope you get some good answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 LIST="a b c . b c . d"
 i=0
 for f in $LIST ; do 
    echo -e "$i\t$f"
    i=$(($i+1))
 done | sort -u -k 2 | sort -n | cut -f2
```

Comment: Interestingly simple approach. Ill test it against some other sample lists later today. Thanks.

Comment: This worked very well for what Im doing. Thanks for the help!